# MySQL Stored Procedure not invoking correct CASE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm developing a 2 player Android game which makes use of a MySQL table called 'games' to keep track of the games and the players assigned to it. Its structure is as follows:

['games' table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ3p4.png)

The logic I am using to connect the players is:
1) Look for incomplete games (i.e. where isGameComplete=0) and see if any of those have a player1 not set for it (i.e. where player1_id = null AND player2_id != null). If any found, assign joining player to that game by setting his id in place of player1_id. 
2) Look for incomplete games (i.e. where isGameComplete=0) and see if any of those have a player2 set for it (i.e. where player2_id = null AND player1_id != null). If any found, assign joining player to that game by setting his id in place of player2_id.
3) If both above cases fail, then make a new record in games table and set player1_id  = the joining player's id.

I made a stored procedure from PhpMyAdmin that I call via the server side script as soon as a player starts the game to carry out the above mentioned logic.

```
Begin
    Set @gameId = -1;
    Set @player1empty = -1;
    Set @player2empty = -1;

    SET @player1empty = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games WHERE player1_id is NULL AND player2_id is NOT NULL AND isGameComplete=0 LIMIT 1);
    SET @player2empty = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games WHERE player2_id is NULL AND player1_id is NOT NULL AND isGameComplete=0 LIMIT 1);

    CASE
    WHEN @player1empty=1 THEN
    UPDATE games SET player1_id = userId, id =(@gameId:=id ) WHERE player1_id is NULL AND isGameComplete=0 LIMIT 1;
        Set joinedGame = @gameId;
    WHEN @player2empty=1 THEN
    UPDATE games SET player2_id = userId, id =(@gameId:=id ) WHERE player2_id is NULL AND isGameComplete=0 LIMIT 1;
        Set joinedGame = @gameId;
    ELSE 
    Insert into games (player1_id,gameType_id) Values (userId,8);
    Set joinedGame = last_insert_id();
    end CASE;
END
```

However, for some reason, a new player is always added in a new game record as Player1 even if there is a NULL in player2_id in an incomplete game. I've tried running the Count query separately and it does return the value 1 for both player 1 and player 2 null cases. Any help would be appreciated! And advise on how to avoid issues like this in the future.
Thanks!

Comment: Are there more than one incomplete game? Count returns the count and you’re only comparing to 1 and not >0 so if there’s two it won’t match. Limit only applies to results, of which here will only ever be one row: the count of all incomplete games. It won’t limit the set that is counted.

Comment: Hi. Yes more than one incomplete games are possible, but I have it set to LIMIT 1 just for the sake of being able to use it in the CASE statement. So I'm assuming that player1_id or player2_id will always either be 1 leading it to one of the first 2 cases otherwise will remaining in the initialized value of -1 leading it to the ELSE block.
But yes, I think >1 should work too.

Comment: As I mentioned, limit only limits the output, not the input. Run the queries manually and see what they return first when debugging and it’ll show if your assumptions are correct

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood what you meant. Tried it manually and it returns a value > 1. Fixed the code by changing the case to check for values greater than 0. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `LIMIT` is to limit the amount of rows *returned* by the query. When you run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games WHERE player1_id is NULL AND player2_id is NOT NULL AND isGameComplete=0 LIMIT 1
```

it will never have more than one row in the result, which is the number of matching rows in the table. The `LIMIT` here does nothing. If there was a grouping, for example, the limit might affect the results.

You should compare to “more than zero” here to make the logic work with any number of incomplete games. Otherwise it will only match the situation where there is a single incomplete game.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Accepted the answer, I had been testing on a small sample size earlier and coincidentally it always had 1 entry where the player_id was null in an incomplete game, so it slipped by.